Jhipster with couchdatabase, Serialization or Mapping problem
all returned values are null except for a couple of fields
what I tried

created a user then validated it
when sigining in the app throws an exception as it just returned the login only and all other details are null except for login, createdDate and lastModified date

how can I troubleshoot this issue?

Ok I just commented this out in databaseConfiguration and everything worked out :)
//    @Bean(name = BeanNames.COUCHBASE_CUSTOM_CONVERSIONS)
//    public CouchbaseCustomConversions customConversions() {
//        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
//        converters.add(ZonedDateTimeToLongConverter.INSTANCE);
//        converters.add(NumberToLocalDateTimeConverter.INSTANCE);
//        converters.add(BigIntegerToStringConverter.INSTANCE);
//        converters.add(StringToBigIntegerConverter.INSTANCE);
//        converters.add(BigDecimalToStringConverter.INSTANCE);
//        converters.add(StringToBigDecimalConverter.INSTANCE);
//        converters.add(StringToByteConverter.INSTANCE);
//        converters.add(UUIDToStringConverter.INSTANCE);
//        converters.add(StringToUUIDConverter.INSTANCE);
//        return new CouchbaseCustomConversions(converters);
//    }

//    @Override
//    public MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter(
//        CouchbaseMappingContext couchbaseMappingContext,
//        CouchbaseCustomConversions couchbaseCustomConversions
//    ) {
//        MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter = super.mappingCouchbaseConverter(
//            couchbaseMappingContext,
//            couchbaseCustomConversions
//        );
//        ((GenericConversionService) mappingCouchbaseConverter.getConversionService()).addConverter(StringToObjectConverter.INSTANCE);
//        return mappingCouchbaseConverter;
//    }

